# Are there any viable replacements for Indium-Tin Oxide electrodes?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, material-science, conductors

I am looking to obtain a metal oxide ceramic that can be synthesized from a Sol-Gel procedure that is both conductive and flexible. Indium-Tin oxide does apply in this case, however the cost of Indium, combined with the fact that Indium-Tin oxide is more of an alloy, does not make it viable. Transparency is not an issue for this application.

Comment: How about Gallium-Doped Zinc Oxide? That seems to be an emerging alternative to Tin-Doped Indium oxide

Comment: Gallium-doped Zinc Oxide might be electrically conductive, but I do not see it being very flexible beyond a thing strip and not in a more bulky configuration, which is part of the requirement.

Comment: The most commonly used alternative to ITO I've seen is fluorine-doped tin oxide, it's a lot cheaper but has similar properties (although that may make it not viable for other similar reasons to FTO, but it may be worth a look).